# Please help with deciphering the meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning, nuances, expressions

> お見合いの相手は、理想を絵に描いたような男性だった。

First part is something like: ***since he/she was/is an omiai partner*** or ***since they met in omiai*** . I’m having difficulty in understanding the second.

Explanation says:

> 理想を絵に描いたような  is an idiomatic usage for one or something that suits something to a tee, that is “the very picture of~..”

I’d highly appreciate if you could help me with any simpler explanation.

Comment: Where are you seeing 'since' ?

Comment: @user27280 sorry I didn’t show the sentence in the context. But I’m guessing it sounds something similar with the end. Might be wrong tho, please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @Sarah Mirzezadeh   If there is a possibility that the previous sentence contains context which might be necessary to adequately understand and explain the sentence in question it should be linked or included as well. Again, I'm still not seeing anything that could be thought of as 'since' anywhere in the sentence. I suggest, initially, focusing on the first clause and translating it more simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the first part just says the topic of the sentence is `お見合いの相手`, `an omiai partner`. I don't think there's any connection with `since`.

The second part you don't really need to already know the idiom to understand it.

Let's focus on 理想を絵に描いたような. The parts before the ~ような is actually a clause by itself. ような means **like**  or **similar to**.

For that clause, the を particle tells is that 理想 is the direct object. What's the verb for it? 描いた. So we know the clause's main action is 理想を描いた: `ideal(s) depicted`.

Next, we need to figure out what 絵に means. The に here describes the target of the clause: the depiction as/into a painting.  理想を絵に描いた thus means `An ideal depicted as a painting`.

Then, 理想を絵に描いたような男性だった means

> A man who was like an ideal depicted as a painting

Using more idiomatic English, you might get something similar to the explanation you were given. And if you connect it with the first part, you'll see that the man that is being described is the omiai partner.

Comment: Thank you tons!!!! As for the “since”, I’m still a beginner and make mistakes/misunderstandings here and then. But next time I’ll be careful enough to post the whole context. Thank you again